# Пунктуация в предложении разговорного стиля

Tags: пунктуация, разговорная-речь

**Книга спрятана там, куда(,) чтобы добраться, надо поднапрячься.**
Предложение само по себе не сильно согласованное, но таким и должно быть.
Я полагаю, что отмеченная скобками запятая не нужна: иначе *"чтобы добраться"* приобретает вставной характер, но извлечь это словосочетание нельзя, потому что остаётся бессмысленное *"куда надо поднапрячься"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Книга спрятана там, куда **чтобы добраться, надо поднапрячься**.*

Да, запятая здесь не ставится. Фактически СПП "чтобы добраться, надо поднапрячься" имеет **фразеологический** устойчивый характер и употребляется в значении "сложно добраться".

Тогда мы получаем предложение: *Книга спрятана там, **куда сложно добраться**.*
Это СПП с придаточным местоименно-определительным.